# What is the easy way to start memory dump analysis?

Tags: memory-management, minidumps

Can anyone help me to know what all skills are required before one can start analysing Windows memory dump.

Any reference on where to start would be appreciated (Beginners level)

Comment: is the question answered?

Comment: Unfortunately asking for learning resources is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and select here the `Debugging Tools for Windows`.

[image]

Now run `Windbg.exe` (from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\windbg.exe"` if it is a 64Bit dump file or from `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x86\windbg.exe"` if it is a 32bit dmp file), click on `File`->`Symbol File Path` and enter `srv*C:\symbols\microsoft*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;`

Now open the dmp and run **!analyze -v**. Now read the [documentation of the STOP code at the msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to understand what it means.

[Microsoft explained it here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) in a video a bit. They also explain some other useful commands.